# Editor html using rows and columns from bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any html editor like summernote or tinyMCE that allows adding rows and columns from bootstrap?

I have followed @Korgrue advice and I found that I can create custom buttons using summernote too. But my code is putting raw text on the textarea, it doesnt change the html into bootstrap. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id="summernote"></div>

    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.2/summernote.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var HelloButton = function (context) {
              var ui = $.summernote.ui;

              // create button
              var button = ui.button({
                contents: '<i class="fa fa-child"/> Hello',
                tooltip: 'hello',
                click: function () {
                  // invoke insertText method with 'hello' on editor module.
                  context.invoke('editor.insertText', '<div class="row">Row</div>');
                }
              });

              return button.render();   // return button as jquery object 
            }

            $('#summernote').summernote({
              toolbar: [
                ['mybutton', ['hello']]
              ],

              buttons: {
                hello: HelloButton
              }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in TinyMCE. You have to set up a custom button for the toolbar, and define what content you want it to generate (in html, as a string). Add one for columns, and one for rows. For columns, you will need to define a text field where the user can input the amount of columns and let the onclick handle appending the column count to the html element for you.

https://www.tinymce.com/docs/demo/custom-toolbar-button/

```
 tinymce.init({
      selector: 'textarea',
      height: 500,
      toolbar: 'mybutton',
      menubar: false,
      setup: function (editor) {
      editor.addButton('mybutton', {
      text: 'My button',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function () {
        editor.insertContent('&nbsp;<b>It\'s my button!</b>&nbsp;'); // <--- this line is where you would define the HTML to use on button click.
      }
    });
  },
  content_css: [
    '//fast.fonts.net/cssapi/e6dc9b99-64fe-4292-ad98-6974f93cd2a2.css',
    '//www.tinymce.com/css/codepen.min.css'
   ]
  });
```

Comment: I tried what you suggested on summernote. I edited my post with my code. When the button generates the text, it doesnt change the bootstrap code into html. Its a raw text. Do you know what am I missing?